# React: Data transformation to advanced form (or how to work with my data in graphs of react chartjs 2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three records (JSONs) in database and I fetch them in main.js and in return statement I send them to next file by this `<StatisticListGraph items={loadedStatistics} />`. In StatisticListGraph I am mapping data (you can see bellow). I get data in this form there:
[image: final form of data]

So I have three JSONs files and my graph is rendered three times, but I want to render graph only once and data have into the desired form: `data: [2,5,6,8,7]` -> here should be my props properties from database, not only same dummy numbers.

**Question**:  How can I get the correct form of data for graphs react chartjs 2 - so to the form data: [props0.goals, props1.goals, props2.goals, ...] ?

How can I transform data from three JSONs to one JSON? For example I have:

```
JSON A:{
id: 58987,
name: JsonA,
goals: 5,
assist:4
},
JSON B:{
name: JsonB,
goals: 15,
assist:2
},

JSON C:{
name: JsonC,
goals: 10,
assist:21
}
```

and I want to have one JSON, where I want this form:

```
JSON Z: {
name: [JsonA, JsonB, JsonC],
goals:  [5,15,10],
assist: [4,2,21]
}
```

main.js

```
    const [loadedStatistics, setLoadedStatistics] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchStatistics = async () => {
            try {
                const responseData = await sendRequest(
                    'http://localhost:5000/api/statistics'
                );
                setLoadedStatistics(responseData.statistics);
            } catch (err) { }
        };
        fetchStatistics();
    }, [sendRequest]);
```

StatisticsListGraph.js

```
    return (
        <div>
            {props.items.map(
                filteredStatistic => (
                        <StatisticItemGraph
                            key={filteredStatistic.id}
                            id={filteredStatistic.id}
                            name={filteredStatistic.name}
                            goals={filteredStatistic.goals}
                            shots={filteredStatistic.shots}
                            shotsOnGoal={filteredStatistic.shotsOnGoal}
                            ballPos={filteredStatistic.ballPos}
                            tackles={filteredStatistic.tackles}
                            fouls={filteredStatistic.fouls}
                            yellowCards={filteredStatistic.yellowCards}
                            redCards={filteredStatistic.redCards}
                            offsides={filteredStatistic.offsides}
                            cornersKicks={filteredStatistic.cornersKicks}
                            freeKicks={filteredStatistic.freeKicks}
                        />
                ))}
        </div>
    );
```

StatisticItemGraph .js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';


const StatisticItemGraph = props => {  
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {   
        setData({
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
            label: ['# of Votes'],
            data: [2,5,6,8,7],  **// data: [props.goals] = 3 graphs**
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 3
          }]
        })
    
      }, [setData]);

    return (
            <div>
                <Doughnut data={data} />
            </div>
        );
}

export default StatisticItemGraph;
```

Comment: your goal is not clear,

Comment: you are calling your StatisticItemGraph three time hence showing three time. If you want to render this only once then don't pass the data in StatisticsListGraph in map function.
First create the data that you need to send to the StatisticItemGraph and then pass the same to render it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited my post after Question, there I have my 
specific problem, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method which will return you data in desired format. I have written logic to convert your data in desired format.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 58987,
  name: 'JsonA',
  goals: 5,
  assist: 4
}, {
  name: 'JsonB',
  goals: 15,
  assist: 2
}, {
  name: 'JsonC',
  goals: 10,
  assist: 21
}]
const result = {}
data.forEach(item => {
  if (!result.name) {
    result.name = []
  } else {
    result.name.push(item.name)

  }
  if (!result.goals) {
    result.goals = []
  } else {
    result.goals.push(item.goals)
  }
  if (!result.assist) {
    result.assist = []
  } else {
    result.assist.push(item.assist)
  }

})

console.log(result)
```

Now use this data in StatisticsListGraph component and pass this to the child component.

```
return ( < div >
    <
    StatisticItemGraph name = {
      result.name
    }
    goals = {
      result.goals
    }
    /> <
    /div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I only changed if else statements, creating array for variables I have before foreach function, because than first JSON collection was not included.